# Are there any OpenSource ArcObjects Projects?

Tags: arcobjects, open-source-gis

One of the major benefits of developing GIS applications based on opensource libraries, is that many projects spring up on top of them which are also opensource.

Well designed opensource projects are great for seeing:

- which coding patterns should be used
- what coding styles to follow
- how to structure larger projects
- what unit tests to include
- autodocumentation tools and procedures
- sourcecontrol workflows

The [ArcObjects Code Gallery](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api?sortBy=ratingCount&sort=up) seems the best place to look, but most examples I've looked at are very small pieces of functionality or single tools, rather than full applications.

The [SharpGIS](http://sharpgis.net/) project is a nice .NET example to follow, but are there any ArcObjects specific projects?

---

**Updated with Examples:**

http://eagl.codeplex.com/

> Easy ArcGIS Library is a set of C# .net classes that wrap the common
>   functionality of ArcObjects, that help ArcGIS developers do a lot of
>   common functions in less time and direct way.

And from the same developer:

http://arcgisslcontrols.codeplex.com/

> ArcGISSLControls is a set of ArcGIS Silverlight controls that is built
>   on top of the ArcGIS Silverlight SDK, it is developed in C#
>   programming language.

Comment: Are there any other examples of open source projects using proprietary libraries? Most open source licenses require full source code release, which means no proprietary (closed-source) libraries.

Comment: Anything based on the .NET framework would fall into this category. There are not many .NET OS projects, but there are a few e.g. http://www.screwturn.eu/ and most projects in http://www.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 Some good examples... guess you answered your own question! It would seem they do exist but not in large numbers. Probably because most AO projects are proprietary in functionality or purpose.

Comment: I've released some AO code in sourceforge. Altought I'm still mainting that code, I just don't have as much time as I would like. In fact, after 2 or 3 months perfecting this library on another gig, I'm ready to commit a little more stuff. Comments and critics are welcome. http://sourceforge.net/projects/gisactiverecord/ If any of you guys and gals want to help, just let me know.

Comment: Also I'm compiling a lot of common routines and I wish to release them. These are to be for next month or so :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[GDAL](https://gdal.org/) has an [ArcObjects driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_ao.html) and you can [see the source code in SVN the tree](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/arcobjects/).
The [Ziggis project is ArcObject's based and open source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100929064542/http://code.google.com:80/p/ziggis/source/browse/#svn/trunk%3Fstate%3Dclosed). I know they have a newer version that is also open source, but I cannot find the source location.

Otherwise, [ESRI's Arcscript's site](https://codesharing.arcgis.com/) is another place to look at.

Comment: +1 Ziggis project is a nice example, although now seems to have ceased development (and moved to proprietary!). Also good to have a C++ AO example.

Answer (score 3):

Hy,
I created a Java Print SOE for high quality printouts with a Flex widget.

The code is available in the CodeGallery:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6809086326ea4c76bf026a32bb9dd698

Tom

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had a chance to play with [Earthworm - An ORM for Esri Geodatabase (via ArcObjects)](https://github.com/jshirota/Earthworm), but it looks good.